# No qualifying bean of type on spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

i create spring mvc + jpa project, I get an exception when I receive a `bean` my `repository` class. Configuration jpa is correctly, but i get error in this part of class `controller`.

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    private ApplicationContext context;
    private PupilService pupilService;
    private PupilRepository pupilRepository;

    private void setUpField(){
        if (context == null){
            context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanClass.class);
        }
        if (pupilService == null){
            pupilService = context.getBean(PupilServiceImpl.class);
        }
        System.out.println("1");  //print
        if (pupilRepository == null){
            System.out.println("2");  //print
            pupilRepository = context.getBean(PupilRepository.class);
            System.out.println("3"); // no
        }
    }
```

**Exception**

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ua.korbo.persistence.repository.PupilRepository] is defined
```

**StackTrace**

```
**exception**

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ua.korbo.persistence.repository.PupilRepository] is defined
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

**root cause**

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ua.korbo.persistence.repository.PupilRepository] is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
    com.ua.korbo.web.controller.WebController.setUpField(WebController.java:36)
    com.ua.korbo.web.controller.WebController.printService(WebController.java:55)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**PersistenceContext**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"persistence.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {

    public PersistenceContext() {
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the datasource bean
     * */

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
        dataSourceConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSourceConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSourceConfig.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty("db.username"));
        dataSourceConfig.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("db.password"));
        return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the entity manager factory
     * */
    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("entity");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * The method that configures the transaction manager
     * */
    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**BeanClass**

```
@Configuration
@Import({PersistenceContext.class})
public class BeanClass {

    @Bean
    public PupilService serviceDao(){
        return new PupilServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

**PupilRepository**

```
public interface PupilRepository extends CrudRepository<Pupil, Long> {
}
```

Comment: Annotate `PupilRepository` with `@Repository` annotation. Also, use `@Autowired` to inject beans into controller

Comment: When i use `@Autowired` I get `WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.`

Answer (score 0):

Please annotate interface PupilRepository with @Repository .

```
  @Repository
public interface PupilRepository extends CrudRepository<Pupil, Long> {
}
```

And to access the same in controller you need to Autowire it . Something like

```
@Autowired
private PupilRepository pupilRepository;
```

Try and let me know ,if you face any problem.

Comment: I'm added `@Repository` and `@Autowired`, but I have new exception `WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.`